# How to remount dev/sdb1 on external HDD?

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

Beginner here.

I plugged my external HDD, but couldn't copy anything there since it was saying 'the destination is read-only'.

Whatever, I decided to sudo cp the file, but wrote the wrong path. In fact, I wrote:

```
sudo cp file.zip /dev/sdb1
```

Should I say, that I realized that I f*cked up the mounting segment or smth, cause it is not showing neither on windows nor on ubuntu anymore. Windows is asking to reformat it (there's stuff there, that needs to be saved).

If I run GParted and select /dev/sdb, then it's showing an exclamation mark (!) in red next to /dev/sdb1, file system: uknown

```
alex@desktop:~/Downloads$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 103,4G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 931,5G  0 part
```

Is there any way to save the info from the HDD? Or somehow remount the usb back? :/

Upd: fdisk -l results can be found here: http://pastebin.com/MumiuHZ9

UPD2: Solution found. 
After trying testdisk and all possible variations, I have finally brought it back to life. 
The last 2 operations that I made:
ran **chkdsk G:/f**  with administrator rights on windows7 and then back on ubuntu i have run:

```
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/external/ -o force && sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

My greatest appretiation to @GAD3R for helping me all this way.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu, please click  [here](http://askubuntu.com/posts/851910/edit) to edit and add the output of `fdisk -l`

Comment: @GAD3R, I have updated the post with fdisk -l output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mount point:

```
sudo mkdir /media/your_mount_point
```

Mount your partition:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/your_mount_point
```

Copy your files to `/media/your_mount_point`

**edit**

Mount your external disque on `fstab`:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orig
```

edit the `/etc/fstab` file.

```
UUID=put_the_uuid_here  /media/your_mount_point  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0
```

Change the `locale=en_US.utf8` with yours.

Run `sudo blkid` to get the uuid

To fix the master boot record , install `mbr` and `syslinux`:

```
sudo apt-get install mbr syslinux
```

Run :

```
sudo install-mbr /dev/sdb
```

or

```
dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: alex@desktop:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/Elements
    alex@desktop:~$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/Elements
NTFS signature is missing.
    Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
    The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
    Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Comment: A more readable version: http://pastebin.com/5eJRi6pj
It doesn't seem to allow me to do that.

Comment: Are you trying `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` ?

Comment: It says, it failed to detect if it is mounted or not. 
More detailed msg: http://pastebin.com/NuqSGLdH

Comment: Use `testdisk` to recover the `mbr` there is an example [here](http://superuser.com/a/1084006/550853)

Comment: I've ended up here: http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/16/1122/h_1479830165_5600569_3c99a99b57.png

Comment: the edit of /etc/fstab file really screwed somehow my system, I could not load further than the grub2 bash. After copying the original file back to it's place, I made it though. Heads up!